# Pandas - Get value from second dataframe based on combination of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with a problem at the moment.

Basically I have two DataFrames.

One that is an export from my ERP System and gives me the current physical stock level, which should be enhanced with stock reservations per sales channel, e.g.

```
Stock = pd.DataFrame(data={'SKU': [1,2,3], 'PhysicalStock': [100,1,2], 'FirstSeenInStock': [2,5,200], 'SafetyStock_Platform1': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'SafetyStock_Platform2': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

The columns SKU, Physical Stock and First Seen in Stock (which is days since this product was first seen with stock) come from the ERP system. The columns for Safety stock should be derived from another DataFrame, which is maintained by someone for all marketplaces and looks like this:

```
SafetyStock = pd.DataFrame(data={'FromAgeDays': [0,2,9], 'ToAgeDays': [3,10,999], 'SafetyStock_Platform1': [10,1,0], 'SafetyStock_Platform2': [5,3,0]})
```

What I tried with iloc is to identify the values from the dataframe SafetyStock and copy them into the Stock dataframe, considering the following logic:

- Stock['FirstSeenInStock'] >= SafetyStock['FromAgeDays']
- Stock['FirstSeenInStock'] <= SafetyStock['ToAgeDays']
- Right column for platform, thus I named the columns the same in both dataframes

The desired outcome would be the following:

```
DesiredOutcome = pd.DataFrame(data={'SKU': [1,2,3], 'PhysicalStock': [100, 1, 2], 'FirstSeenInStock': [2,5,200], 'SafetyStock_Platform1': [10,1,0], 'SafetyStock_Platform2': [5,3,0]})
```

Comment: Try : ``pd.merge_asof(Stock, SafetyStock, left_on='FirstSeenInStock', right_on='FromAgeDays').query('FirstSeenInStock <= ToAgeDays')``. With your data, I do not think you need the query part

Comment: You are right, I did not need the query part. The following code produced exactly the desired outcome: `merge_asof(Stock, SafetyStock, left_on='FirstSeenInStock', right_on='FromAgeDays', allow_exact_matches=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use merge function in pandas which is essentially known as "join" in the world of database.

Merging based on conditions is not well developed in pandas, it is known as "non equi join".

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried already but did only find examples for merge & join, where the key to merge on is exactly the same, which is not the case for me.

Can you maybe provide an example of how you would do it with merge and/ or join?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. This is called rolling joins and they are easier to do in R, for example.

Comment: I just checked googel and merge_asof might be a working solution, if there are no alternatives.

Comment: Merge based on a condition is not a rolling join. A rolling join is often based on a time series where you jump forwards or backwards. The question is a non equi join

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks for the correction. Updated my answer.